# Sending straight JSON to API using requests?

Tags: python, json, api

The jist of my problem is that there is an open API that contains road info that I'm trying to pull very specific information from. The JSON request I'm trying to make looks like:

```
data1 = """
<REQUEST>
    <LOGIN authenticationkey=""/>
        <QUERY objecttype="RoadData" schemaversion="1.0">
            <INCLUDE>SpeedLimit</INCLUDE>
            <INCLUDE>RoadMainNumber</INCLUDE>
            <INCLUDE>RoadSubNumber</INCLUDE>
        </QUERY>
        <QUERY objecttype="RoadGeometry" schemaversion="1.0">
            <INCLUDE>Geometry.WGS843D</INCLUDE>
            <INCLUDE>RoadMainNumber</INCLUDE>
            <INCLUDE>RoadSubNumber</INCLUDE>
        </QUERY>
</REQUEST>
"""
```

and I'm simply sending a request to the correct URL with this as my json code, i.e:
`respones = requests.post(url, data=data1)` but I'm only getting response 400 which leads me to believe my JSON request is wrong, however they supply an in-house console for testing your requests directly on their website and there it's working. Am I simply stupid here and I'm sending it incorrectly?

Tried looking at similar problems on stackoverflow and online but every single issue uses a dictionary to map their requests but that's not possible here? At least I don't know how to get the  keyword in a dictionary as a condition since the sice of the dataset requires this.

Comment: That's not a JSON request. This looks like XML. Be sure to check out [JSON Notation](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp)
That said, passing XML can also be done by giving the header `Content-Type: application/xml`. Be sure to pass headers so that the receiving server side knows what type of data you're sending. The rest of the `requests.post` looks good

Comment: Oh lord you're absolutely correct... I was arguing with my partner saying it was an XML request but he was adamant so I caved in. Thank you, getting responses now.